# How to call an Office Add-In function from PowerPoint slide?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Is there a way to call Office Add-In function from PowerPoint slide without executing a macro? For instance on button click that is placed on a slide.

Comment: Hi Zimny, can you please give some example regarding your question.

Comment: The button is placed on the slide. For instance an interactive button. On button click I want to call a function from Add-In. Is that possible and if so how?